# How can I get specific json data value via the key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

let us say I have the following json in my local storage

```
top: [ {"id","one","name":"java"},
       {"id","two","name","javascript"},
       {"id","three","name","jquery"]
     ]
```

The problem here is how can i get the id just by using the name value?
For instance, if I want get the id value `"two"`, I need to be able to make the query using `"javascript"` then reach the value `"two"`.
Is there a way to achieve the above described problem?

Comment: Sorry, thats not a valid JSON...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's convert your input to object then access it as property

```js
var input = [{
            "id":"one",
            "name":"java"
          },
          {
            "id":"two",
            "name":"javascript"
          },
          {
            "id":"three",
            "name":"jquery"
          }];

     
var result = input.reduce((acc, b) => { 
  acc[b.name] = b.id;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result['javascript']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `Array#find`.your json is invalid .you could change format like this below

```js
var toper = [{
    "id": "one",
    "name": "java",
  },
  {
    "id": "two",
    "name": "javascript",
  },
  {
    "id": "three",
    "name": "jquery",
  }
]

function find_id(str) {
  return toper.find((a) => {
    if (a.name == str.trim()) {
      return a
    }
    }).id
}
console.log(find_id('javascript'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has some typo mistakes. It should be like Tai's example above.

To retrieve it from the local storage (as text) and use it (as json object):

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(myText)
```

Then:

```
for (var i=0 ; i<myJson.length ; i++) {
    if myJson[i].name == "javascript" {
        var a = myJson[i].id;
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```